# What is best approach on designing this generic abstract class? (Part 3)

Tags: .net, oop, .net-2.0

Based on previous question, I've changed the context as follow:

I have abstract class called Tenant and CustomerList. The Tenant in this case is like owner of the application for multi tenant application model and CustomerList is a collection of Customer class.

The relationship between these 2 class are Many to One relationship.

```
public abstract class Tenant 
{    
  protected Int32 id;    
  protected String name;    
  public Int32 ID { get; set; }    
  public String Name { get; set; }    
  public abstract bool Add();    
  public abstract bool Update();    
  public abstract bool Delete();  
}

public class ApplicationTenant: Tenant
{    
   public ApplicationTenant() { }    
   public override Int32 ID    
   {      
      get { return id; }         
      set { id = value; }    
   }    
   public override String Name    
   { 
     get { return name; }         
     set { name= value; }    
   }    
}

public abstract class CustomerList
{
   protected Tenant tenant;

   public abstract Tenant Tenant {get; set;} 

   public abstract List<Customer> GetAll();   
}

public abstract class CorporateCustomerList : CustomerList
{
   privateT enant tenant;

   public override Tenant Tenant 
   {
     get(return tenant;) ; 
     set(Tenant = tenant);
   }


   public override List<Customer> GetAll()
   {     
      ... calling from data service
      return t;
   }
}
```

With the OO design above, we know that method of List GetAll();   needs to be overrided.

BUT the issue are:

1) The return value of the `GetAll()` in the **CorporateCustomer** is always going to be `List<CorporateCustomer>.` It meeans that I have to override `List<Customer> Get()` without being implementation and create another following method

```
public List<CorporateCustomer > GetAll()  {     return ???;  }
```

2) If I override anyway for this method above and on the return I just cast it ... it won't work anyway. ?!!? Can't casting to List from List

3) The property below:

```
public override Tenant Tenant    
{         
   get { return tenant; }         
   set { tenant= value; }    
}
```

means again I have to override this BUTI don't I really used this cause the **CorporateCustomer** is always going to be used the ApplicationTenant instead as return NOT Tenant.

```
public CorporateTenant Tenant    
{         
   get { return corporateTenant; }         
   set { corporateTenant= value; }    
}
```

So is this the right design? Cause it's kinda waste of the abstraction.

Some people suggests to use Generic abstract class instead which I am not sure it's going to help anyway. I did try to use generic on the method but the definition of the definition needs to be the same from the top level of abstrction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you've come across (IMO) the two main failings and pitfalls of C# - override and generic co- and contra-variance. I'll address the problems in the most sensible order

With regards to problem 3, you cannot override a method returning a BaseClass with a method returning an SubClass. C# does not allow you to change method parameters when overriding, even if the change will be type-safe, and from what I gather this will not be addressed anytime soon, as it is quite a severe breaking change, and CLR dependent. A workaround is to change CustomerList to an interface (which should be OK, as it's only got abstract members) and do something like this (ignoring GetAll for the moment):

```
public interface ICustomerList
{
    Tenant Tenant {get; set;}
}

public abstract class CorporateCustomerList : ICustomerList
{
    private CorporateTenant tenant;

    public CorporateTenant Tenant 
    {
        get { return tenant; }
        set { tenant = value; }
    }

    Tenant ICustomerList.Tenant 
    {
        get { return Tenant; }
        set { Tenant = value; }
    }
}
```

Your other problem with GetAll is that `List<BaseClass>` is not in any way castable or convertable to `List<SubClass>` - this is a common problem on SO, and will be somewhat addressed for generic interfaces in C#4. There are several workarounds:

1. Use an array to store your customers, have GetAll return an IList rather than a List, and override using an explicit interface implementation as above - due to historical reasons, arrays *do* support element type covariance (sorry about the formatting, markdown seems to be doing odd things)

   ```
   public interface ICustomerList
   {
       public IList<Customer> GetAll();
   }

   public abstract class CorporateCustomerList : ICustomerList
   {
       private CorporateCustomer[] customers;

       public IList<CorporateCustomer> GetAll()
       {
           get { return customers; }
           set { customers= value; }
       }

       IList<Customer> ICustomerList.GetAll()
       {
           get { return customers; }
           set { customers = value; }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change GetAll to return an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than a `List<T>`, then use the yield return syntax to turn an `IEnumerable<CorporateCustomer>` into an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, but is slightly more complicated with the setter...

   ```
   public abstract class CorporateCustomerList : ICustomerList
   {
       // as above...
       private CorporateCustomer[] customers;

       IEnumerable<Customer> ICustomerList.GetAll()
       {
           get
           {
               foreach (CorporateCustomer c in customers)
               {
                   yield return c;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this gives you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

this is messy.....  I don't think you have clear concepts?   something called a list, should be a list not a container for another list?  I'm actually unsure what you are trying to abstract.   Tenant seems like the wrong thing?

its hard to tell from your example.

but a tenant  is really   a   Person/Entity that has a 'Contract' called a "tennancy".....  I'm not sure about the rest of your question as there isn't enough context

Comment: I have abstract class called Customer. To get the collection of Customer (GetAll()) doesn't make sense if I put under here ... so I need to put under CustomerList (or Customers).

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, whenever you're representing real people in any application, consider using  `Person` and `Role` classes.  That way, you can give any `Person` any number of responsibilities, and you don't have to create weird and wonderful class hierarchies.

For your example, you'll have several **Roles**:

```
public class Customer : Role
{
 ...
}

public class CorporateCustomer : Role
{
 ...
}

public class Tenant : Role
{
 ...
}
```

And a Person class that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
   Details Details {get;set;}
   IList<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}
```

Use the Role classes to encapsulate the appropriate logic.